# Acronis: Should recovery partitions be added during backup / restore?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-image, acronis-trueimage

I use Acronis True Image for many years and generally include the recovery partitions of primary disk (C:) to the backup file and select these partitions while restore. However, I am not sure if I am wrong and if I should only use primary partition for backup and restore. I know there is a "Switch to Disk mode" option, but it shows the entire disk that I partitioned to C:\ and D:\ drives.

Could you clarify me about this issue and let me know if it is possible to recover using the backup of only primary partition **or** using the backup of primary and recovery partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best backup would be that of the entire disk and all its partitions,
also including the boot sector.
This will ensure that you can restore the whole disk.
You will also need, for the worst case when the disk is lost, Acronis boot media
with which to restore the disk.

As regarding your question: You should decide for which kind of disaster you wish
to be prepared. Some possibilities are:

- Total disk lose and new disk installed : Needs a total disk backup
- The system `C:` partition becoming unusable : Needs only a backup of `C:`
- The system `C:` partition and the recovery becoming corrupted : You need to backup both.

If you take an image backup only of `C:` and the disk is totally lost, you will need
to partition the new disk anew, install Windows on the new `C:` partition and the
new recovery partition, then return the old `C:` from backup.
This should work, but is not guaranteed, as you are mixing two Windows installations.

(As regarding the Acronis tool - this is paid software. Just a remark:
An alternative free software that is just as good is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).)

Comment: Many thanks for these useful tips and detailed explanation. In this scene, I think I should take C partition and and its recovery partition(s). Then, when restoring I can use only C partition or I can use different combination (C partition + Recovery partition(s)) according to the scenario. For example if my PC is getting too slow and I want to restore Windows, then I just need to restore C partition. Is that **completely** true?

Comment: Nothing is ever completely true regarding computers. I can only say that it's likely to work well. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens))

Comment: No, I mean that the approach I said is possible or not?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible.

Comment: I did. Thank you and have a nice day (or year).

Comment: Thanks a lot to you, I learned many things from your good answer. regards...